# Ajax, Percorrer cada elemento

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Tenho um ajax que me retorna isso.

```
{curso: "Administração", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
1
:
{curso: "Administração", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
2
:
{curso: "Administração", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
3
:
{curso: "Administração", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
4
:
{curso: "Administração", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
5
:
{curso: "Administração", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
6
:
{curso: "Administração", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
7
:
{curso: "Arquitetura e Urbanismo", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
8
:
{curso: "Arquitetura e Urbanismo", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
9
:
{curso: "Arquitetura e Urbanismo", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
10
:
{curso: "Arquitetura e Urbanismo", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
11
:
{curso: "Ciências Contábeis", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
12
:
{curso: "Ciências Contábeis", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
13
:
{curso: "Ciências Contábeis", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
14
:
{curso: "Ciências Contábeis", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
15
:
{curso: "Direito", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
16
:
{curso: "Direito", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
17
:
{curso: "Direito", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
18
:
{curso: "Direito", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
19
:
{curso: "Direito", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
20
:
{curso: "Direito", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
21
:
{curso: "Direito", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
22
:
{curso: "Direito", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
23
:
{curso: "Direito", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
24
:
{curso: "Direito", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
25
:
{curso: "Direito", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
26
:
{curso: "Direito", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
27
:
{curso: "Direito", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
28
:
{curso: "Direito", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
29
:
{curso: "Direito", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
30
:
{curso: "Direito", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
31
:
{curso: "Direito", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
32
:
{curso: "Direito", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
33
:
{curso: "Direito", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
34
:
{curso: "Direito", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
35
:
{curso: "Direito", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
36
:
{curso: "Direito", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
37
:
{curso: "Direito", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
38
:
{curso: "Direito", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
39
:
{curso: "Direito", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
40
:
{curso: "Engenharia Civil (4)", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
41
:
{curso: "Engenharia Civil (5)", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
42
:
{curso: "Engenharia Civil (5)", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
43
:
{curso: "Engenharia de Produção", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
44
:
{curso: "Engenharia de Produção", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
45
:
{curso: "Gestão Financeira", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
46
:
{curso: "Gestão Financeira", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
47
:
{curso: "Marketing", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
48
:
{curso: "Serviço Social", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
49
:
{curso: "Serviço Social", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
50
:
{curso: "Serviço Social", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
51
:
{curso: "Serviço Social", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
52
:
{curso: "Sistemas de Informação", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
53
:
{curso: "Sistemas de Informação", nDeAluSelecionadosRespondentes: 0, nDeAlunSelecionadosNaoRespondentes: 0, numeroDeAlunosSelecionados: 0, percentDeAluNaoSelecionadoRespondentes: 0, …}
length
:
54

$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "url",
     success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, val){
            if(val.curso[i] == val.curso[i-1]){
                console.log('Teste');
            }
        });
        console.log( data[0] );
     },
     error: function (ex) {
         alert("Erro: " + ex.status);
     }
})
```

Gostaria de saber, como faria para criar uma tabela para cada Curso, por exemplo

Administração uma tabela,
Arquitetura e Urbanismo Outra tabela

Comment: Com essa estrutura, você tem de ir olhando um a um e verificando se o curso mudou do anterior pro atual. Se mudou, fecha a tabela atual e inicia uma nova.

Comment: faria isso com o $.each(data, function(k, v) {
    
}); ?

Comment: Se estiver usando jQuery, pode ser sim. Pode ser um `for` normal também. O que você tem é uma array, precisa percorrer todos os itens dela um por um.

Comment: Não to conseguindo, não consigo comparar com o anterior, pra poder criar uma nova tabela

Comment: Edite a pergunta e inclua o trecho relevante de código da sua tentativa. Sem ver o código fica difícil te ajudar mais precisamente.

Comment: Pronto, já editei

Comment: "pra poder criar uma nova tabela" - Mostrar os cursos numa tabela do html (`<table>`) ?

Comment: isso, gostaria de criar uma tabela para cada curso, enquanto for o mesmo curso, adicionar linhas na tabela, e quando mudar o curso, criar uma nova tabela e ir adicionando linhas nela

Comment: Mas cada linha é o que ? Tem como colocar a informação de uma linha de forma detalhada? Independentemente disso terá que utilizar um `for` ou um `forEach`